# Feed template function element from tuple at runtime?

Tags: c++, runtime, tuples

In C++ I have a tuple with some elements in it:

```
std::tuple <int, char> my_tuple(3, 'q');
```

And some template function that perfectly works both on integers and chars:

```
template <class T> void my_function(T);
```

Now, say that at runtime I want to run my_function on one of the elements of my tuple (but I don't know which). I noticed that it is not possible to do something like:

```
unsigned int n;

// Give a value to n

my_function(std::get <n> (my_tuple));
```

However, in principle what I need should be identical to something like:

```
unsigned int n;

// Give a value to n

switch(n)
{
    case 0:
      my_function(std::get <0> (my_tuple));
      break;
    case 1:
      my_function(std::get <1> (my_tuple));
      break;
    default:
      // Do nothing or throw an exception
}
```

So it sounds to me like this should be feasible.. is it?

Comment: std::get returns the n-th tuple element of type whatever it is, which should get carried to the template function, so it looks like it ought to be possible. Did you try it? Does it not work?

Comment: I tried doing something like `unsigned int n; cin>>n; my_function(std::get <n> (my_tuple))` but I got `no matching function for call to get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n` being a runtime value, it can't be used to instanciate a template at compile-time. Your `switch` works because you manually instanciate each `std::get<N>`, and wire them to the corresponding runtime value.

But yeah, it's a bit of a chore to write that braindead `switch` tree. Why not let the compiler generate the boilerplate with a bit of TMP ?

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void my_function(T);

// Test specialisations to see what's going on
template <> void my_function(int i) { std::cout << "int " << i << '\n'; }
template <> void my_function(char c) { std::cout << "char " << c << '\n'; }

namespace detail {
    // Available in std in C++14
    template <bool P, class T>
    using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<P, T>::type;

    // Mockup function signature to pick up the call when enable_if shunts
    template <std::size_t N, class T = void>
    void callMyFunc(T&&, ...) {
        assert(!"Index not in range !");
    }

    // "Simple" recursive solution, removes itself from the overload set
    // to stop recursion
    template <std::size_t N, class... Ts,
        class = enable_if_t<N < sizeof...(Ts), void>>
    void callMyFunc(std::tuple<Ts...> &tuple, std::size_t n) {
        return n == N
            ? my_function(std::get<N>(tuple))
            : callMyFunc<N + 1>(tuple, n);
    }
}

// Tiny user-friendly wrapper
template <class... Ts>
void callMyFunc(std::tuple<Ts...> &tuple, std::size_t n) {
    detail::callMyFunc<0u>(tuple, n);
}

int main(int, char**) {
    std::tuple <int, char> my_tuple(3, 'q');

    // Success.
    callMyFunc(my_tuple, 0u);
    callMyFunc(my_tuple, 1u);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following may help:

```
template <typename T> struct caller;

template <typename... Ts> struct caller<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    template <typename F>
    void operator() (F f, std::tuple<Ts...>& t, int n)
    {
        (*this)(f, t, n, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>());
    }
private:
    template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is>
    void operator() (F f, std::tuple<Ts...>& t, int n, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        std::function<void(F, std::tuple<Ts...>&)> fs[] = { &helper<F, Is>... };
        fs[n](f, t);
    }

    template <typename F, std::size_t I>
    static void helper(F f, std::tuple<Ts...>& t)
    {
        f(std::get<I>(t));
    }

};

template <typename F, typename T>
void call(F f, T& t, int n)
{
    caller<T>()(f, t, n);
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c891ff3d32421994)

Comment: Haha, I went that way at first but I wasn't fond of the type-erasure.